# Bash script wait for processes and get return code

Tags: linux, bash, process, array

I am trying to create a script which will start many background command.
For each background command I need to get the return code.

I have been trying the following script :

```
 #!/bin/bash
set -x
pid=()
return=()


for i in 1 2
do
 echo start $i
 ssh mysql "/root/test$i.sh" &
 pid[$i]=$!
done

for i in ${#pid[@]}
do
echo ${pid[$i]}
wait ${pid[$i]}
return[$i]=$?

if [ ${return[$i]} -ne 0 ]
then
  echo mail error
fi

done

echo ${return[1]}
echo ${return[2]}
```

My issue is during the wait loop, if the second pid finish before the first one, I'll not be able to get the return code.

I know that I can run wait pid1 pid2, but with this command I can't get the return code of all commands.

Any idea ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can do this by using a temporary directory.

```
# Create a temporary directory to store the statuses
dir=$(mktemp -d)

# Execute the backgrouded code. Create a file that contains the exit status.
# The filename is the PID of this group's subshell.
for i in 1 2; do
    { ssh mysql "/root/test$i.sh" ; echo "$?" > "$dir/$BASHPID" ; } &
done

# Wait for all jobs to complete
wait

# Get return information for each pid
for file in "$dir"/*; do
    printf 'PID %d returned %d\n' "${file##*/}" "$(<"$file")"
done

# Remove the temporary directory
rm -r "$dir"
```

Answer (score 10):

The issue is more with your

> ```
> for i in ${#pid[@]}
> ```

Which is `for i in 2`.

It should rather be:

```
for i in 1 2
```

or

```
for ((i = 1; i <= ${#pid[@]}; i++))
```

`wait "$pid"` *will* return the exit code of the job with `bash` (and POSIX shells, but not `zsh`) even if the job had already terminated when `wait` was started.

Answer (score 5):

**A generic implementation without temporary files.**

```bash
#!/usr/bin/env bash

## associative array for job status
declare -A JOBS

## run command in the background
background() {
  eval $1 & JOBS[$!]="$1"
}

## check exit status of each job
## preserve exit status in ${JOBS}
## returns 1 if any job failed
reap() {
  local cmd
  local status=0
  for pid in ${!JOBS[@]}; do
    cmd=${JOBS[${pid}]}
    wait ${pid} ; JOBS[${pid}]=$?
    if [[ ${JOBS[${pid}]} -ne 0 ]]; then
      status=${JOBS[${pid}]}
      echo -e "[${pid}] Exited with status: ${status}\n${cmd}"
    fi
  done
  return ${status}
}

background 'sleep 1 ; false'
background 'sleep 3 ; true'
background 'sleep 2 ; exit 5'
background 'sleep 5 ; true'

reap || echo "Ooops! Some jobs failed"
```

Comment: Thank you :-) This is exactly what I was looking for!

Answer (score 1):

Stéphane's answer is good, but I would prefer

```
for i in ${!pid[@]}
do
    wait "${pid[i]}"
    return_status[i]=$?
    unset "pid[$i]"
done
```

which will iterate over the keys of the `pid` array, regardless of which entries still exist, so you can adapt it, break out of the loop, and re-start the whole loop and it'll just work. And you don't need consecutive values of `i` to begin with.

Of course, if you're dealing with thousands of processes then perhaps Stépane's approach would be fractionally more efficient when you have a non-sparse list.

Comment: naming you array `return` freaked me out, man!

Comment: @ToddiusZho is `return_status` better?

Comment: (To be fair, the original question names the variable `return`; I was just copying that.)

Answer (score 1):

Bash 4.3 added `-n` to the `wait` builtin, and `-p` was added in version 5.1.

From https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Job-Control-Builtins.html

`wait -n`

> If the -n option is supplied, wait waits for a single job from the list of pids or jobspecs or, if no arguments are supplied, any job, to complete and returns its exit status. [...]

`wait -p`

> If the -p option is supplied, the process or job identifier of the job for which the exit status is returned is assigned to the variable varname named by the option argument. [...]

The combination of the two options means Bash 5.1+ is actually quite decent at basic multiprocessing. The main drawback now is really just tracking/managing stdout/stderr.

```
_job1 () { sleep "$( shuf -i 1-3 -n 1 )"s ; true ; }
_job2 () { sleep "$( shuf -i 1-3 -n 1 )"s ; return 42 ; }

limit="2"
i="0"

set -- _job1 _job2
while [ "$#" -gt "0" ] ;do

    until [ "$i" -eq "$limit" ] ;do
        printf 'starting %s\n' "$1"
        "$1" &
        pids[$!]="$1"
        i="$(( i + 1 ))"
        shift
    done

    if wait -n -p ended_pid ;then
        return_code="$?"
        printf '%s succeeded, returning "%s"\n' "${pids[ended_pid]}" "$return_code"
    else
        return_code="$?"
        printf '%s FAILED, returning "%s"\n' "${pids[ended_pid]}" "$return_code"
    fi
    unset 'pids[ended_pid]'
    i="$(( i - 1 ))"

done

while [ "${#pids[@]}" -gt "0" ] ;do
    if wait -n -p ended_pid ;then
        printf '%s succeeded, returning "%s"\n' "${pids[ended_pid]}" "$?"
    else
        printf '%s FAILED, returning "%s"\n' "${pids[ended_pid]}" "$?"
    fi
    unset 'pids[ended_pid]'
done
```

More information (though not on `wait -p`): http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ProcessManagement