# reliable return code of background process

Tags: bash, shell-script, background-process, exit

Let's assume the following piece of bash code:

```
foo > logfile 2>&1 &
foo_pid=$!

while ps -p$foo_pid
do
    ping -c 1 localhost
done

wait $foo_pid

if [[ $? == 0 ]]
then
    echo "foo success"
fi
```

Is it safe to assume that `$?` indeed contains the return code of `foo` and not the return code of `ping`? If the answer to that question is: "You cannot assume that." then how can I modify this piece of code to be sure that `$?` always contains the return code of `foo`?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

With `bash`, you'll have that guarantee unless you've started another background job (and beware that background jobs can be started with `&` but also with `coproc` and with process substitution) between the `foo &` and the `wait`.

[POSIX requires that a shell remembers the exit status of at least 25 jobs after they're gone](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/wait.html#tag_20_153_16), but `bash` remembers a lot more than that.

Now, if you do:

```
foo & pid=$!
...
bar &
wait "$pid"
```

You've got no guarantee that `bar` will not be given the same pid as `foo` (if `foo` has terminated by the time `bar` starts), so even though it's unlikely, `wait "$pid"` may give you the exit status of `bar`.

You can reproduce it with:

```
bash -c '(exit 12; foo) & pid=$!
         while : bar & [ "$pid" != "$!" ]; do :;done
         wait "$pid"; echo "$?"'
```

which will (eventually) give you `0` instead of `12`.

To avoid the problem, one way would be to write it as:

```
{
  foo_pid=$!

  while ps -p "$foo_pid"
  do
      ping -c 1 localhost
  done

  bar &
  ...

  read <&3 ret
  if [ "$ret" = 0 ]; then
    echo foo was sucessful.
  fi
} 3< <(foo > logfile 2>&1; echo "$?")
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe your assumption is correct. Here's an extract from `man bash` regarding waiting for background processes.

> If  n specifies  a  non-existent  process or job, the return status is
>   127.  Otherwise, the return status is the  exit  status  of  the last process or job waited for.

So maybe you should check for 127

There's a similar question with a completely different answer than might help.

[Bash script wait for processes and get return code](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/65618/bash-script-wait-for-processes-and-get-return-code)

edit 1

Inspired by @Stephane's comments and answers I have expanded his script. 
I can start about 34 background processes before it starts to loose track.

tback

```
$ cat tback 
plist=()
elist=()
slist=([1]=12 [2]=15 [3]=17 [4]=19 [5]=21 [6]=23)
count=30

#start background tasksto monitor
for i in 1 2 3 4
do
  #echo pid $i ${plist[$i]} ${slist[$i]}
  (echo $BASHPID-${slist[$i]} running; exit ${slist[$i]}) & 
  plist[$i]=$!
done

echo starting $count background echos to test history
for i in `eval echo {1..$count}`
do
  echo -n "." &
  elist[$i]=$! 
done
# wait for each background echo to complete
for i in `eval echo {1..$count}`
do
  wait ${elist[$i]}
  echo -n $? 
done
echo ""
# Now wait for each monitored process and check return status with expected
failed=0
for i in 1 2 3 4
do
  wait ${plist[$i]}
  rv=$?
  echo " pid ${plist[$i]} returns $rv should be ${slist[$i]}"
  if [[ $rv != ${slist[$i]} ]] 
  then
    failed=1
  fi
done

wait
echo "Complete $failed"
if [[ $failed = "1" ]]
then
  echo Failed
else
  echo Success
fi
exit $failed
$
```

on my system produces

```
$ bash tback
14553-12 running
14554-15 running
14555-17 running
starting 30 background echos to test history
14556-19 running
..............................000000000000000000000000000000
 pid 14553 returns 12 should be 12
 pid 14554 returns 15 should be 15
 pid 14555 returns 17 should be 17
 pid 14556 returns 19 should be 19
Complete 0
Success
```

Comment: No, see my [comment to umlaute's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/116098/reliable-return-code-of-background-process/116105#comment180523_116099), and try it for yourself with `bash -c '(exit 12) & sleep 1; wait "$!"; echo "$?"'`

Comment: I've never seen `bash` loose track (even after starting thousands of jobs), my example was demonstrating the pid being reused, which may be what you observed in your case as well.