# zombie process reap without "wait"

Tags: wait, zombie-process

I know if a subprocess does not get reaped properly, it will become a zombie and you can see it by `ps` command.

Also the "wait [pid]" command will wait for subshell running on the background until it finishes and reap it.

I have a script like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
sleep 5 &

tail -f /dev/null
```

My question is, I don't use `wait` after `sleep 5 &` and the parent shell will never terminate because of `tail`, then why the `sleep 5 &` will not become a zombie? I see it disappear after finishing in `ps`, not sure who reaps it?

Comment: Is this answered by https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/538958/bash-when-is-a-pid-exactly-freed-up ? [Look for **Unfortunately**].

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is one of the pitfalls with having a shell mimic the OS API.  It does create confusion.  In this case you are confusing [wait()](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/wait.2.html) (linux API) with [wait](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Job-Control-Builtins.html) (bash function).

Simply enough, Bash takes care of reaping processes for you, you don't generally need to think about this.  The `wait` bash command has no effect on reaping processes.

When your child job terminates, bash will be informed via a [SIGCHLD signal](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal.7.html).  This will when that happens bash will stop whatever it was doing for a moment and reap the stopped child.  It then goes back to whatever it was doing.

Answer (score -1):

Your use of "`&`" requested the parent process to put "`sleep 5`" in the background, so it is the parent process that will harvest the `sleep 5`.