# Collect exit codes of parallel background processes (sub shells)

Tags: bash, shell-script, shell, subshell

Say we have a bash script like so:

```
echo "x" &
echo "y" &
echo "z" &
.....
echo "Z" &
wait
```

is there a way to collect the exit codes of the sub shells / sub processes? Looking for way to do this and can't find anything. **I need to run these subshells in parallel, otherwise yes this would be easier.**

I am looking for a **generic** solution (I have an unknown/dynamic number of sub processes to run in parallel).

Comment: I'm going to suggest you figure out what it is that you want and then ask a new question, trying to be clear on exactly the behaviour you're looking for (perhaps with pseudocode or a larger example).

Comment: I actually think the question is good now - I have a dynamic number of sub processes. I need to collect all the exit codes. That's all.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The answer by Alexander Mills which uses handleJobs gave me a great starting point, but also gave me this error

> warning: run_pending_traps: bad value in trap_list[17]: 0x461010

[Which may be a bash race-condition problem](https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/bug-bash/2012-11/msg00006.html)

Instead I did just store pid of each child and wait and gets exit code for each child specifically. I find this cleaner in terms of subprocesses spawning subprocesses in functions and avoiding the risk of waiting for a parent process where I meant to wait for child. Its clearer what happens because its not using the trap.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# it seems it does not work well if using echo for function return value, and calling inside $() (is a subprocess spawned?) 
function wait_and_get_exit_codes() {
    children=("$@")
    EXIT_CODE=0
    for job in "${children[@]}"; do
       echo "PID => ${job}"
       CODE=0;
       wait ${job} || CODE=$?
       if [[ "${CODE}" != "0" ]]; then
           echo "At least one test failed with exit code => ${CODE}" ;
           EXIT_CODE=1;
       fi
   done
}

DIRN=$(dirname "$0");

commands=(
    "{ echo 'a'; exit 1; }"
    "{ echo 'b'; exit 0; }"
    "{ echo 'c'; exit 2; }"
    )

clen=`expr "${#commands[@]}" - 1` # get length of commands - 1

children_pids=()
for i in `seq 0 "$clen"`; do
    (echo "${commands[$i]}" | bash) &   # run the command via bash in subshell
    children_pids+=("$!")
    echo "$i ith command has been issued as a background job"
done
# wait; # wait for all subshells to finish - its still valid to wait for all jobs to finish, before processing any exit-codes if we wanted to
#EXIT_CODE=0;  # exit code of overall script
wait_and_get_exit_codes "${children_pids[@]}"

echo "EXIT_CODE => $EXIT_CODE"
exit "$EXIT_CODE"
# end
```

Comment: cool, I think `for job in "${childen[@]}"; do` should be `for job in "${1}"; do` though, for clarity

Comment: the only concern I have with this script, is if `children_pids+=("$!")` is actually capturing the desired pid for the sub shell.

Comment: I tested with "${1}" and it doesn't work. I'm passing an array to the function, and apparently that needs special attention in bash. $! is the pid of the last spawned job, see http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/internalvariables.html It seems to work correctly in my tests, and I'm now using in the in unRAID cache_dirs script, and it seems to do its job. I'm using bash 4.4.12.

Comment: nice yep seems like you are correct

Answer (score 31):

Use [`wait` with a PID, which](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#index-wait) will:

> Wait until the child process specified by each process ID *pid* or job specification *jobspec* exits and return the exit status of the last command waited for.

You'll need to save the PID of each process as you go:

```
echo "x" & X=$!
echo "y" & Y=$!
echo "z" & Z=$!
```

You can also enable job control in the script with `set -m` and use a `%n` jobspec, but you almost certainly don't want to - [job control has a lot of other side effects](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Job-Control).

`wait` will return the same code as the process finished with. You can use `wait $X` at any (reasonable) later point to access the final code as `$?` or simply use it as true/false:

```
echo "x" & X=$!
echo "y" & Y=$!
...
wait $X
echo "job X returned $?"
```

`wait` will pause until the command completes if it hasn't already.

If you want to avoid stalling like that, you can [set a `trap` on `SIGCHLD`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#index-trap), count the number of terminations, and handle all the `wait`s at once when they've all finished. You can probably get away with using `wait` alone almost all the time.

Comment: ughh, sorry, I need to run these subshells in parallel, I will specify that in the question...

Comment: nevermind, maybe this works with my setup...where does the wait command come into play in your code? I don't follow

Comment: @AlexanderMills They *are* running in parallel. If you have a variable number of them, use an array. (as e.g. [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/65618/bash-script-wait-for-processes-and-get-return-code?rq=1) which may thus be a duplicate).

Comment: yes thanks I will check that out, if the wait command pertains to your answer, then please add it

Comment: You run `wait $X` at any (reasonable) later point.

Comment: ok thanks, sorry but what does the $X represent?

Comment: I mean $X represents the PID of the first process, but why would you want to use that with wait?

Comment: Because you wanted to collect the exit code of that process.

Comment: oh, I need the exit codes of all the sub processes, not just the first one

Comment: I guess like you said I can loop over the results and than call wait on each one. (right?)

Comment: You'll never guess what happens when you run `wait $Y`.

Comment: LOL, ok I see, but it's not super clear, let me update your answer, thanks :)

Comment: Yeah @arberg used your idea and solved it your way, I changed the accepted answer to argberg's. if you think his answer needs to work please comment on that answer below thanks.

Comment: So how do you know what job `Y` returned?

Comment: @pmor wait on the PID of Y in the same way.

Comment: Consider subshells X and Y, each executed in parallel. Consider that we need to implement "if any subshell failed, then all subshells failed" logic. If waiting of X and Y is done sequentially (as in your answer) AND if, for example, Y failed while waiting of X, then there is no need to wait X. How to implement, more precisely, "if any subshell failed, then kill immediately all other subshells"?

Answer (score 9):

I think the other answers are needlessly convoluted.

If you save your background pids in an array as you launch them, you can wait for them explicitly and collect the return codes in a second array:

```
pids=()
echo "x" & pids+=($!)
echo "y" & pids+=($!)
echo "z" & pids+=($!)
....
echo "Z" & pids+=($!)

# wait and collect return codes
rets=()
for pid in ${pids[*]}; do
    wait $pid
    rets+=($?)
done
echo "Return codes: ${rets[*]}"
```

The return codes are collected **in the same order** as the jobs were launched.

If you only need to know if one or more jobs failed, you don't need to collect all return codes:

```
error=false
for pid in ${pids[*]}; do
    if ! wait $pid; then
        error=true
    fi
done
```

Comment: Thank you for also showing what to do when you only need to know if any jobs failed.

Answer (score 5):

Use a `compound command` - put the statement in parentheses:

```
( echo "x" ; echo X: $? ) &
( true ; echo TRUE: $? ) &
( false ; echo FALSE: $? ) &
```

will give the output

```
x
X: 0
TRUE: 0
FALSE: 1
```

A really different way to run several commands in parallel is by using [GNU Parallel](https://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/). Make a list of commands to run and put them in the file `list`:

```
cat > list
sleep 2 ; exit 7
sleep 3 ; exit 55
^D
```

Run all the commands in parallel and collect the exit codes in the file `job.log`:

```
cat list | parallel -j0 --joblog job.log
cat job.log
```

and the output is:

```
Seq     Host    Starttime       JobRuntime      Send    Receive Exitval Signal  Command
1       :       1486892487.325       1.976      0       0       7       0       sleep 2 ; exit 7
2       :       1486892487.326       3.003      0       0       55      0       sleep 3 ; exit 55
```

Comment: ok thanks, is there a way to generify this? I don't just have 3 sub processes, I have Z sub processes.

Comment: I updated the original question to reflect that I am looking for a generic solution, thanks

Comment: One way to generify it might be to use a looping construct?

Comment: Looping? Do you have a fixed list of commands or is that controlled by the user? I am not sure I understand what you are trying to do but maybe `PIPESTATUS` is something you should check out. This `seq 10 | gzip -c > seq.gz ; echo ${PIPESTATUS[@]}` returns `0 0` (exit code from first and last command).

Comment: Yeah essentially controlled by the user

Comment: @oletange, your edit should really have taken the form of a separate answer

Comment: @iruvar I believe you mistake my edit (#3) for hschou's (#2). Mine is correcting a speling msitake and adding -j0. Hardly worth its own answer.

Answer (score 5):

If you had a good way to identify the commands, you could print their exit code to a tmp file and then access the specific file you're interested in:

```
#!/bin/bash

for i in `seq 1 5`; do
    ( sleep $i ; echo $? > /tmp/cmd__${i} ) &
done

wait

for i in `seq 1 5`; do # or even /tmp/cmd__*
    echo "process $i:"
    cat /tmp/cmd__${i}
done
```

Don't forget to remove the tmp files.

Answer (score 3):

`script3` will be executed only if `script1` and `script2` are successful and `script1` and `script2` will be executed in parallel:

```
./script1 &
process1=$!

./script2 &
process2=$!

wait $process1
rc1=$?

wait $process2
rc2=$?

if [[ $rc1 -eq 0 ]] && [[ $rc2 -eq 0  ]];then
./script3
fi
```

Comment: AFAICT,  this is nothing more than a rehash of [Michael Homer’s answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/344360/23408#344367).

Answer (score 2):

this is the generic script you're looking for. The only downside is your commands are in quotes which means syntax highlighting via your IDE will not really work. Otherwise, I have tried a couple of the other answers and this is the best one. This answer incorporates the idea of using `wait <pid>` given by @Michael but goes a step further by using the `trap` command which seems to work best.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

set -m # allow for job control
EXIT_CODE=0;  # exit code of overall script

function handleJobs() {
     for job in `jobs -p`; do
         echo "PID => ${job}"
         CODE=0;
         wait ${job} || CODE=$?
         if [[ "${CODE}" != "0" ]]; then
         echo "At least one test failed with exit code => ${CODE}" ;
         EXIT_CODE=1;
         fi
     done
}

trap 'handleJobs' CHLD  # trap command is the key part
DIRN=$(dirname "$0");

commands=(
    "{ echo 'a'; exit 1; }"
    "{ echo 'b'; exit 0; }"
    "{ echo 'c'; exit 2; }"
)

clen=`expr "${#commands[@]}" - 1` # get length of commands - 1

for i in `seq 0 "$clen"`; do
    (echo "${commands[$i]}" | bash) &   # run the command via bash in subshell
    echo "$i ith command has been issued as a background job"
done

wait; # wait for all subshells to finish

echo "EXIT_CODE => $EXIT_CODE"
exit "$EXIT_CODE"
# end
```

thanks to @michael homer for getting me on the right track, but using `trap` command is the best approach AFAICT.

Comment: You can also use SIGCHLD trap to process the children when they exit, such as printing out the status at that time. Or updating a progress counter:   declare a function then use "trap function_name CHLD" though that may also require an option to be turned on in a non-interactive shell, such as possibly "set -m"

Comment: Also "wait -n" will wait for any child and then return the exit status of that child in the $? variable.  So you can print progress as each one exits. However note that unless you use the CHLD trap, you may miss some child exits that way.

Comment: @Chunko thanks! that is good info, could you maybe update the answer with something you think is best?

Comment: thanks @Chunko, trap works better, you're right. With wait <pid>, I got fallthrough.

Comment: Can you explain how and why you believe the version with the trap is better than the one without it?  (I believe that it’s no better, and therefore that it is worse, because it is more complex with no benefit.)

Comment: I think @argberg's answer is better now, I may delete this answer soon

Answer (score 2):

Quick and dirty solution:

```
for job in `jobs -p`; do wait $job || exit; done
```

Exits the script if any asynchronous job fails

---

Disclaimer: This will not check the status codes of jobs that completed very quickly (i.e. before the line is called)

Answer (score 1):

Another variation of @rolf 's answer:

Another way to save the exit status would be something like

```
mkdir /tmp/status_dir
```

and then have each script

```
script_name="${0##*/}"  ## strip path from script name
tmpfile="/tmp/status_dir/${script_name}.$$"
do something
rc=$?
echo "$rc" > "$tmpfile"
```

This gives you a unique name for each status file including the name of the script which created it and its process id (in case more than one instance of the same script is running) which you can save for reference later and puts them all in the same place so you can just delete the whole subdirectory when you're done.

You can even save more than one status from each script by doing something like

```
tmpfile="$(/bin/mktemp -q "/tmp/status_dir/${script_name}.$$.XXXXXX")"
```

which creates the file as before, but adds a unique random string to it.

Or, you can just append more status information to the same file.

Answer (score 1):

I think this might be the simplest one:

```
cmd1 & pids+="$! "
cmd2 & pids+="$! "
cmd3 & pids+="$! "

for p in $pids; do wait $p || err=$?; done

[[ $err ]] && echo "ERROR: $err"
```

It checks if there was any error in the background process. One can easily improve it if errors need to be collected.